# Showing the date on the system tray with the metacity flashback (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: date, clock, metacity

I'm clarifying "with metacity" because I assume that's what is disqualifying the advice I found on multiple posts. I had this fixed back on ubuntu 16 with a different pc but I can't for the life of me remember how I did it.

I've tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

I've also looked for it in gnome-tweaks but apparently version 3.28.1 does not have the *top* menu (it also lost the extensions and workspaces menus now that I look at it). Maybe I should get another version of gnome-tweak-tools...

But still, if I understand correctly, gnome-tweaks is only a gui for gsettings and, right now, I have my terminal saying

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date 
true
```

while my tray has no date on it...

Comment: @PRATAP yes, it is not default but it is one of the most used ones (since a lot of old farts like me enjoy classic gnome). see [here](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/05/how-to-install-classic-gnome-flashback-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the below command to show the date

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-date true`

alternatively use `dconf-editor` GUI tool and search for `datetime` and make your changes accordingly..

[image]

[image]